# Access, Visual Basic: Pull record based on two values

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm having trouble finding a good answer for this problem. I think I'm pretty close.

**Example**: Find a record based on UserID and UserTicket. There are duplicate UserID and each has a UserTicket.

> UserID -> 100 UserTicket -> 1
>
> UserID -> 100 UserTicket -> 2
>
> UserID -> 101 UserTicket -> 1
>
> UserID -> 100 UserTicket -> 3

So I first enter the UserID into a search box, using FindFirst. That part works, the first record populates my form. Then I have a dropdown box of the UserTickets, and it appears to populate correctly, but when I select from that list the form down not repopulate.

So for the first query I use this:

```
rs.FindFirst "[UserID]=" & UserID
```

And for the second I try and use this (does not work)

```
rs.FindFirst "[UserID]=" & UserID & " AND [UserTicket]=" & UserTicket
```

Also here is the SQL I use to populate the dropdown list, which perhaps is incorrect:

```
 SELECT Users.id, Users.UserTicket 
  FROM Users 
  WHERE (((Users.UserID)=[Form].[current_user]));
```

Where current_user is an auto populating field that keeps track of the UserID that has currently filled my form.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Once you enter a 'UserID' into the search box, and find it, do you then requery the 'dropdownlist'? Hard to tell what other code you may have.

Comment: When you say, "does not work" what do you mean?  Do you get an error?  What is the error?  Is `UserTicket` defined as a string in the table?

Comment: Also what is the query that creates the recordset?  For what it's worth, I made a test table and did the `FindFirst` method on a recordset opening the table and was able to do it on 2 parameters, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @OpiesDad What did you query look like? For "down not work" I just mean that the form view does not update the values to the correct record. I have it Refresh, but nothing. So my second query doesn't do anything as far as I can tell.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn I do requery the dropdownlist, based on the current UserID. Or thats the plan anyway.

Comment: Might need all of the code that is relevant here.  I made a sample form and was able to get this to work, but admittedly did not set it up exactly how you would have.